# Why does compare works differently in the case of value from the array

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86-64, inline-assembly, att

I am using inline C assembly and I does not understand why does not work cmp command same for this 2 cases.

I have C function:

`int array_max(const int input_array[], const int array_size);`

In the main I created array and passed it in to the function

`int input_array[] = {50,10,3,70,5};`

`printf("%d\n", array_max(input_array, 5));`

Function definition is writed in assembly

```
__asm__
(
"array_max:;"
"   xor     %rdx, %rdx;"
"   movq    $70, %rax;"
"   movq    $50, %rbx;" 

"   cmp     %rbx, %rax;"
"   jge     gr_eq;"
"   movq    %rbx, %rax;"
    
"gr_eq:;"
"   ret"
);
```

In this case is return value 70

```
__asm__
(
"array_max:;"
"   xor     %rdx, %rdx;"
"   movq    $70, %rax;"
"   movq    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %rbx;" // input_array[0] == 50

"   cmp     %rbx, %rax;"
"   jge     gr_eq;"
"   movq    %rbx, %rax;"
    
"gr_eq:;"
"   ret"
);
```

But it this case 50...

Can sameone help me how can I compare passed array values to value in the register? And explain me why this implementation does not work?

Comment: Thank you so much! It works when I store it to the ECX or EDX and compare it with EAX!

Comment: RBX is call-preserved; pick a different register.  (As well as fixing the operand-size of your load).  e.g. `cmpl $70, (%rdi, %rdx, 4)`. Note that compares in opposite order from what you did, with the load result as the right-hand operand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have an array of 32-bit signed `int`s and you are reading 64-bit values from the array (when each element is only 4 bytes in size) and comparing as 64-bit signed integers. If you stepped through the code with a debugger like GDB you should see what is going on. Be forewarned that *RBX* is a non-volatile register in the [AMD64 System V ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI) so its value has to be preserved in a function. You can avoid this by not using any of *RBX*, *RBP*, or *R12-R15* registers.

The simplest of changes would be to do this:

```
__asm__
    (
    "array_max:;"
    "   xor     %rdx, %rdx;"
    "   mov     $70, %eax;"
    "   mov     (%rdi,%rdx,4), %ecx;"
    "   cmp     %ecx, %eax;"
    "   jge     gr_eq;"
    "   mov     %ecx, %eax;"

    "gr_eq:;"
    "   ret"
    );
```

As you move forward you should realize that you are passing `arr_size` as a `const int` which is a 32-bit signed number. As the second parameter that will passed via *RSI*. When passing a 32-bit value, the upper 32-bits of the register (like *RSI*) are undefined. You will have to make sure you [sign extend the 32-bit value to a 64-bit signed value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64269608/3857942). Even better is to change `const int` to `const size_t` which in 64-bit code will be a 64-bit unsigned value.  That puts the responsibility on the caller to put the value into the full register.

A version of the code that continues to use `const int arr_size`; ensures the array size is greater than 0; steps through the array from the last element to the first element could be done this way:

```
__asm__
    (
    "array_max:\n\t"
    "   movsx %esi, %rsi\n\t"          # Sign extend arr_size(ESI) 32-bit value to 64-bit
    "   mov   $0x80000000, %eax\n\t"   # EAX starts as lowest signed integer
    "   jmp   2f\n"
    "1:\n\t"
    "   mov   (%rdi,%rsi,4), %ecx\n\t" # Read current 32-bit signed value from array
    "   cmp   %eax, %ecx\n\t"
    "   jl    2f\n\t"                  # Is current element(ECX) < max value(EAX)?
    "   mov   %ecx, %eax\n"            # If not, update max value with current element
    "2:\n\t"
    "   dec   %rsi\n\t"                # Work backwards through the array
    "   jge   1b\n\t"                  # Until we have finished processing 1st element
    "   ret"                           # Return max array value in EAX  
    );
```

The way this works is that it sets the initial maximum value in *EAX* to the smallest negative value (0x80000000) and starts from the end of the array and compares the current element to the maximum value. If the current element (*ECX*) is greater than the maximum value seen (*EAX*) then set the maximum value to the current element. This continues until the beginning of the array has been processed.

---

### Notes

- You can make some improvements like using one of the [`CMOVcc`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/cmovcc) instructions to set the maximum value with the current element without the branch. It would appear something like:

  ```
  "   cmp     %eax, %ecx\n\t"
  "   cmovg   %ecx, %eax\n"          # Set max value to current element if ECX>EAX
  ```

  Instead of:

  ```
  "   cmp   %eax, %ecx\n\t"
  "   jl    2f\n\t"                  # Is current element(ECX) < max val(EAX)?
  "   mov   %ecx, %eax\n"            # If not, update max value with current element
  ```
- I use the `"\n\t"` (which is newline character followed by tab character) to improve formatting if someone used GCC/CLANG's `-S` option to review generated assembly instructions. You can continue to use `;` instead.
- I use numeric labels to ensure all the labels are unique and don't conflict with any other labels that may be generated by the *C* compiler. More information on this feature can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/817-5477/esqaq/index.html)

  > **Numeric Labels**
  >
  > A numeric label consists of a single digit in the range zero (0)
  > through nine (9) followed by a colon (:). Numeric labels are used only
  > for local reference and are not included in the object file's symbol
  > table. Numeric labels have limited scope and can be redefined
  > repeatedly.
  >
  > When a numeric label is used as a reference (as an instruction
  > operand, for example), the suffixes b (“backward”) or f (“forward”)
  > should be added to the numeric label. For numeric label N, the
  > reference Nb refers to the nearest label N defined before the
  > reference, and the reference Nf refers to the nearest label N defined
  > after the reference.

Comment: What are "1:\n\t", "2:\n\t" and \n\t for? I am learning about inline assembly only for 3 days and it is hard to find resources about it and I did not see anywhere these "commands".

Comment: @Wh1stlee: I update my answer with some additional details. The `\n\t` and the `\n` can end a instruction like `;` but it improves formatting as mentioned in the notes section at the bottom. Everywhere you see `\n\t` or `\n` you can replace it with `;` if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: @Wh1stlee: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info for links.  But when you're just using an asm statement at global scope to define a whole function (instead of simply putting it in a separate file), most of the complexity of *inline* asm doesn't apply (constraints to tell the compiler how to optimize around an Extended Asm statement).  All you're dealing with is just normal GAS syntax, in this case for x86-64 with AT&T syntax.  https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html documents in the GNU `as` manual documents numeric local labels.